# membrane for a reverse osmosis desalination experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, pressure, home-experiment, experimental-technique, osmosis

We are second year cram schoolers , we are currently working on a project tackling water desalination by reverse osmosis and are required to do an experience. During the process, we encountered some difficulties regarding applying pressure and the make up of membranes . Given our unfavorable circumstances (low budget , lack of material ), we were wondering if someone could give us some insights on how to proceed. Although , we have tried to diy one with accessible materials and this is what we could come up with so far .

First ,we took an unglazed flowerpot and we filled its hole with cement, we filled it with a 0.1 mol / L potassium ferrocyanide solution. Simultaneously, we soak it in a 0.1 mol / L copper sulphate solution. After waiting several hours, the two products are going to spread in the parish, one from the inside, the other from the outside. In the middle of the parish, a chemical reaction had taken place , forming a precipitate of copper ferrocyanide which closes the large pores and transforms the pottery into a semi-permeable membrane. Finally, we rinsed the pottery well with water, and left it to soak for several days so as to remove the initial reagents.

However, we didn't meet our expectations and we don't know what is it that we're doing wrong . How thick should the cement layer be ? what are the rinses so as to remove the reagents ? and how could we simulate the pressure in a compartment ?
and is there any other ways to make a membrane to work with ?

Comment: Why can't you buy a RO membrane?

Comment: @DavidWhite No , my project rely on making one so as to prove that I did something by myself .